# How to create search shortcut in vim

Tags: vim

Most of the time I do some regular search like anything that starting with `def`,it should  take my cursor to that place, so  `/def <search character>` . I am thinking to create some shortcut.

I tried doing this

```
command # /def
```

with a hope that if I do <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>#</kbd> it will type `/def<space>`, but it doesn't.

It is throwing error

```
E182: Invalid command name
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: You may want to look into using ctags which would allow you to jump to definitions via `<c-]>` or using the `:tag` command. See `:h tags`. I also know [jedi-vim](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) is popular however I have not used it myself

Comment: i use `ctags` and it serves most of the case. but i was looking for `search shortcut` command. Thanks

Comment: `:nnoremap <f3> :ta<space>` then start typing your function. The `:tag` command can be completed so you can use `<tab>` or `<c-d>` to help you type less. You can also do `:tag /foo` to match a regex to a tag which is useful to match part of a function name.

Comment: ohh that's wonderful. If you put the above comment in answer...i'll upvote it, your call. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are looking for `map` not `command`. try this:

```
nnoremap <F3> /def<space>
```

I didn't map `#`, instead I used `<F3>`, since `#` is very useful in normal mode. you can use `#` if you like.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using `/` to search is to use ctags. Using tags lets you do the following:

- jump to definition under cursor via `<c-]>`
- `<c-w><c-]>` is the same as `<c-]>`, but open definition in new split window
- `:tag {tag_name}` will jump to the definition of `{tag_name}`
- `:tag` uses completion so `<tab>` and `<c-d>` can help you type less
- `:tag` can use a regex to match part of a tag. e.g. `:tag /foo` (use completion with this also)
- Use `<c-t>` to jump back after you visit a definition (It pops the tag stack)
- Look into Tim Pope's [Effortless Ctags with Git](http://tbaggery.com/2011/08/08/effortless-ctags-with-git.html) article for easy tag file generation

For a quick mapping use the following:

```
nnoremap <leader>t :ta<space>
```

More alternatives:

- Look into cscope for more defintion querying fun. See `:h cscope`
- [jedi-vim](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) is a popular python completion plugin. It has go to definition support as well
- Use `:vimgrep`/`:grep`/[ack](http://beyondgrep.com/)/[ag](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ag%20the%20silver%20searcher)/[git-grep](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) to search across several files when tags are not available
- Use `gd` (go to definition) for simple cases. See `:h gd`
- Look into alternative tag generators like [GNU Global](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/) or language specific tag generators. e.g [jstags](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jstags)

For more help please see the following:

```
:h tags
:h ctrl-]
:h ctrl-w_ctrl-]
:h :tag
:h ctrl-t
:h :vimg
:h :grep
:h gd
:h cscope
```